# Result set data sequence issue on Azure SQL v/s SQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure

Currently I am working with Azure SQL; while working with it found issue with data sequence in Azure v/s SQL. When I run query which have good amount of joins applied to it with TOP the result set which I am getting is differing from the result set I get on Normal SQL.

e.g. Select TOP 20 * from ABC JOIN PQR ON ABC.col1=PQR.Col1

Provides me data in diffrent order. Say I do have 300 recors within it I have selected 20 so on azure its gives me o/p Something like 
ID 1,2,6,8,10,3,4,5
where as on SQL 
ID: 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10

I am facing this issue when I go ahead with TOP without top is working in similar manner

NOTE : Data on both DB server is same

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify an ORDER BY then the order in which the data is returned is not guaranteed, and the DB engine will do it however it wants to.  In this instance, since both engines are the same, it's more likely that something else is different in your environments or the way/order in which your data was loaded.  But either way, if you want order in the result set, add an ORDER BY clause in your SQL.